# SQL Server window function with conditions (where clause for incremential loading)

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, row-number, dense-rank

We would like to incrementally load data from one table to another. There is a chance of having duplicates. Actually it should be dead simple, but with increasing data it gets slower.

The easiest part is to extract the data directly.

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM    dbo.source_table s
WHERE   s.load_datetime > ( SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(t.load_datetime) , '0001-01-01')
                                FROM    dbo.target_table AS t
                          )
```

The query plan is very fast and just identifies the delta.

If I want to remove duplicates I added a DENSE_RANK.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT  s.*
                 ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY s.business_key ORDER BY s.load_datetime ) AS row_no
          FROM    dbo.source_table s
          WHERE   s.load_datetime > ( SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(t.load_datetime) , '0001-01-01')
                                      FROM    dbo.target_table AS t
                                    )
        ) AS sub
WHERE   sub.row_no = 1
```

The issue is, that SQL Server is always performing a window function first before it filters on the load_datetime. I changed the query in all different forms and researched the web for solution. I tried it also with CROSS APPLY and CTE:

```
WITH  data
        AS ( SELECT s.*
             FROM   dbo.source_table s
             WHERE  s.load_datetime > ( SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(t.load_datetime) , '0001-01-01')
                                        FROM    dbo.target_table AS t
                                      )
           )
     SELECT *
     FROM   ( SELECT  *
                     ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY business_key ORDER BY load_datetime ) AS row_no
              FROM    data
            ) AS sub
     WHERE  sub.row_no = 1
```

Still sorting the whole table of xx mio rows instead of the delta.

Does anybody have an idea how to get only the first row of a subquery without the windowing function to calculate the whole data set? It needs to be a SELECT or VIEW without a temporary table.

These are the current plans: [brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy2IFSjKg](http://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy2IFSjKg) (fastest, no duplicate check) [brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJJpKSstl](http://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJJpKSstl)(sorting all 50 mio rows) [brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byre5BoFe](http://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byre5BoFe) (with cte same)

I tried removing the column store index and creating useful non-clustered indexes. No effect. Still does the dense-rank before the where clause.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: These are the current plans: 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy2IFSjKg (fastest, no duplicate check)
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJJpKSstl (sorting all 50 mio rows)
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byre5BoFe (with cte same)

Comment: The execution plans say this is column store table, I would update your title and question to include that information.

Comment: @EckhardZemp Dense_Rank will assign identical ordering values the same number.  You may end up with multiple sub.row_no = 1.  

You should be using Row_Number, not Dense_Rank.  With Row_Number every row in the partition gets a unique number even if the ordering key matches.

Comment: @SqlZim I just removed the column store index and created useful non-clustered indexes. No effect. Still does the dense-rank before the where clause. wes-h: I tried both. The goal is to do the windows function on just the incremential data and not on full.

Comment: @EckhardZemp You might try posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EckhardZemp Any update on this?